# Spawning several random objects in several random positions only when a scene begins

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want spawning several random objects in several random positions only when a scene begins. How can I do it? This is my code, but only appears one object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnItems : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] Objetos;

    void Start () 
    {
        int spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
        int objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length);

        Instantiate (Objetos [objectindex], SpawnPoints [spawnindex].position, SpawnPoints [spawnindex].rotation);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the code button to indent the code four spaces. At the moment  the closing } isn't formatted as code, nor are the lines following 'using UnityEngine'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function to do exactly this for a game I'm working on.

```
public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;   

void Start()
{
    SpawnObjects();
}

void SpawnObjects()
{
    foreach(GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions)
    {
        int selection = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
        Instantiate(spawnObjects[selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

The way it works is you place your different locations in a list, and all of the different prefabs of objects you want to spawn in a separate list, then the loop spawns a random object at each of the different positions.

Remember to put:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

At the top of the class in order to use Lists. You could also use Arrays for this, but I personally prefer lists.

And the Start() function is only ever called once per object, so this code will only run once each time the scene is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just with loop

```
    Start()
    {
         int numberOfObjectsToSpawn = 10;
         int spawnindex;
         int objectindex

         for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToSpawn; i++){

         spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
         objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length);


         Instantiate (Objetos [objectindex], SpawnPoints [spawnindex].position, SpawnPoints [spawnindex].rotation);

         }
    }
```

Hope I get your question right.

Comment: I try it but only appears one of the objects again :(

Comment: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnItems : MonoBehaviour {

 public Transform[] SpawnPoints;

 public GameObject[] Objetos;



 void Start () 
 {

  int numberOfObjectsToSpawn = 10;  
  int spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
  int objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length);
   
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToSpawn; i++)
  
  {

  Instantiate (Objetos [objectindex], SpawnPoints [spawnindex].position, SpawnPoints [spawnindex].rotation);

  }
 }

}

Comment: You did it wrong. You need to create random number in every loop as I wrote in that code above. Like this :

               `int spawnindex; 
  int objectindex; 

  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToSpawn; i++) { 

   spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length); 
   objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length); 
   Instantiate (Objetos [objectindex], SpawnPoints [spawnindex].position, SpawnPoints [spawnindex].rotation); 
  }`

Comment: I do it and the console shows this error: error CS0136: A local variable named `spawnindex' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to `spawnindex', which is already used in a `parent' scope to denote something else

Comment: In your loop for you cant use
`int spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);
 
  int objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length);`

use just:

`spawnindex = Random.Range (0, SpawnPoints.Length);

         objectindex = Random.Range (0, Objetos.Length);`

dont write `int` before spawnidex and objectindex in loop

Comment: ok. It works! Thanks!! I sometimes see multiples objects appears in one position. How can I do only one object appears in each position?

Comment: Finally :D You can mark my answer as correct.

This is a bit complicated. You can make list of positions and delete every used position or make array of used positions and every loop check if random position exists in that array.

Comment: Thank you so much Kasta !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are calling `spawnindex` in the `Start()` function.

This means that your `spawnindex` will always be the same number as the `Start()` function more or less only happens once when you hit play mode.

**This also means** `objectIndex` has the same number, so it will always spawn the same object.

This means that all your spawned objects are using the same number to spawn. If you look at your hierarchy your `GameObjects` are probably all in the same position and the same object.

You need to find a way to generate a different number for each `GameObject`. :-)

EDIT:

This code is from one of the tutorials from the Unity website. It spawns objects at a set time rate. You could do the same but have the spawn time rate at a very small number, that way all your `GameObject`'s will appear to have spawned at the same time.

```
void Start ()
    {
        // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
    }


    void Spawn ()
    {
        // If the player has no health left...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f)
        {
            // ... exit the function.
            return;
        }

        // Find a random index between zero and one less than the number of spawn points.
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

        // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position and rotation.
        Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    }
```